# What does the ORG directive do in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

For reference, the code is for the motorola 68008.

Say I have code such as the following:

```
org 200
sequenceO: ds.b 5
sequenceN: ds.b 5

move.w #sequenceO, A0
move.w #sequenceN, A1
```

1. Am I correct in thinking that A0 will hold the value 200 and A1 the value 205?
2. One of the exam questions in a past paper was: "What are the physical addresses of sequence0 and sequenceN?", would the answer be "200 and 205", or would it be "200-204 and 205-209"?
3. I've seen a few pieces of code with multiple org directives, eg;

   org 100

   array1: ds.b 4

   org 300

Am I right in thinking that the last org directive is followed, eg in this case, array1 points to 300?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, that sounds right. The address of `sequenceN` is 5 bytes beyond `sequence0`.
2. "That depends", I guess ... Since it's "addresses" in plural, I guess they wanted the entire range, in which case your latter answer is correct.
3. No, I would expect multiple `org`s to just apply to the code following them, so in that case the `array1` would be at $100. Since no code or data generation happens after the latter `org`, it's basically ignored by the assembler.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "ORG" means "origin" - the first address to be assigned to the code or data segment being emitted.

Comment: That's was what I assumed as well. However, I've not been able to find any details in my lecture notes or on the internet, and I want to make sure I've fully grok how it works. I don't want to make a stupid mistake in the exam where I assume the SequenceO points to 200 when it points to 201.

Comment: And what does "organization directive" mean @dmor?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, 200 and 205
2. Sequence0 starts at 200 and extends for 5 bytes to 204
3. No, array1 starts at 100, anything after the org 300 would start at 300

Answer (score 1):

You're using: `MOVE.W  #sequenceO, A0`

So, you're loading only the lower word (16 bits) of the address into `A0`. 
That'll only work in very low memory ( `A0` under `$00010000`)

In general using a `MOVE.W` on an address register gets tricky.

Try:    `LEA  #sequence0, A0`    (loads a 32-bit address into `A0`)

Most assemblers will also do:

```
MOVEA.L #sequence0, A0
```

Thanks, Dave Small